# It does show a user but it is show in me the all users that I have on the table and I am just looking for one with $_session

Tags: php, html, mysql

> I want to show the info from a espesific user and I have a  $_session
>   working fine but with a table and in this case I want not to use a
>   table I must like use a CSS div and when I did test it show me this
>   error Notice: Undefined index: usuario in when this "usuario" como
>   from the login index file

```
<?php


require("conection/connect.php");

session_start();


$sql="SELECT stu_id,
    f_name,
    s_name,
    l_name,
    sl_name,
    gender,
    dob,
    pob,
    address,
    phone,
    email,
    note
    from tblstudents 
    where stu_id"; //i want to use a where stu_id='".$_SESSION['usuario']."'"; but it is not working show me Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\studentskin\infostudent.php on line 2
    $infostudent=mysql_query($sql);      // but when I did a test with where stu_id"; it is showing me the all users that I have on the table


?>

<html>
<head><center><h3>Alumno</h3></center></head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>::. Secundaria 10 .::</title>                
<link href="css/backgroundcolor.css" />
<body>
<center>
<?php 

while ($tblstudents=mysql_fetch_assoc($infostudent)){

        echo $tblstudents['stu_id'].  
        "<div>".$tblstudents['f_name']." ".$tblstudents['s_name']." ".$tblstudents['l_name']." ".$tblstudents['sl_name']."</div>";
        echo"";
        }       
?>
```

// I want to use a $_session to just log in and show me the info the allready I`ve logged

Comment: can you please post whole your code?

Comment: Can you paste the code where $_SESSION is defined ?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['btn_log'])){
  $uname=$_POST['unametxt'];
  $pwd=$_POST['pwdtxt'];
  $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['unametxt'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pwdtxt'];

        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['unametxt'];
      $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pwdtxt'];
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbluser
        WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$pwd' 
        
       ");

Comment: The all code where I want to show it is there but where I am doing the login session is in other ling mmm let c how I can send to you can you gave to me a email and I will send to you... L. Vadim

Comment: Ok I saw it the rest of the code is that one...     
    
<?php 

  
  echo $_SESSION['usuario'];  // that one is showing me the result like the picture
  echo "<div>".$_SESSION['f_name']." ".$_SESSION['s_name']." ".$_SESSION['l_name']." ".$_SESSION['sl_name']."</div>";// here is showing me Undefined index: s_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\studentskin\infostudent.php on line 59

  
  


//I´ve tried to make to show  me my results but with out a table, because with a table I cand do it very well and I want to uses a DIV with css to make more fancy this php website
    
?>

Comment: @OcYriZjImEneZ please edit your question with extra code and errors, don't put them in comments - it's very hard to read, and others might not see them

Comment: Ok. OK let me edit it

Comment: please show where the bit you commented that starts `if(isset($_POST['btn_log']...` is coded. At the moment it is missing. Also, you have two different sections of PHP. Are they in different files? If so, please state which files they are in. Otherwise it is hard to understand the flow of the code. Finally, one code comment says "This is showing me result like the picture", but there is no picture referenced.

Comment: I ready fix that I am looking for no wi want to use the $_sesion variable that I have on the index file to acces to this information, and the index file is working fine because it is show in me all data from another tables Now just I want to show me the espesific information about the user

Comment: no, you never put that block into the question. And now you've removed a lot of the other info you previously inserted as well. Did you add `session_start();` to the start of the "index" page (presumably that is where `$_SESSION['usuario']` is defined)?

Comment: Also...your code is potentially open to SQL injection, and you are using the mysql_* database library which is deprecated in PHP5.5 and removed entirely in PHP7. It has security vulnerabilities and has had no new features for more than 10 years. If this is a new application, you should **not** be using it under any circumstances. Use MySQLi or PDO instead, and use parameterised queries to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes adyson you are right... but with the other informaion in the other code dont show me any result, and Now I have information results, just I wan to know how I can do it to end my excesice...

Comment: ok well can you answer my question about session_start() in the index page please?

Comment: Yes lets me back to home because I am working and I will post it the index code

Comment: The code you've posted as an answer doesn't answer my question. Show the file where `$_SESSION['usuario']` is _defined_. I mean where you have a line like `$_SESSION['usuario'] = "xyz";` or similar. In that file, you must also have `session_start();` before that line.

Comment: Just I was looking for how I can show the information about a consult I did t's enough, I did and is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
require("conection/connect.php");

session_start();

$sql="SELECT 
    `stu_id`,
    `f_name`,
    `s_name`,
    `l_name`,
    `sl_name`,
    `gender`,
    `dob`,
    `pob`,
    `address`,
    `phone`,
    `email`,
    `note`
    from tblstudents 
    where stu_id='".$_SESSION['usuario']."'";

    $records=mysql_query($sql);

?>




<html>
<head><h1>Informacion</h1></head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>::. Secundaria 10 .::</title>                
<body>

<div>
<center>

<?php

while ($tblstudents=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){


echo "<div>".$tblstudents['stu_id']."<div>";
echo "<div>".$tblstudents['s_name']." ".$tblstudents['s_name']." ".$tblstudents['l_name']." ".$tblstudents['sl_name']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$tblstudents['gender']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$tblstudents['dob']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$tblstudents['pob']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$tblstudents['address']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$tblstudents['phone']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$tblstudents['email']."</div>";
echo "<div>".$tblstudents['note']."</div>";




}      

?></center>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: please don't post this as an answer, it's not an answer - edit the question if you have an update. If you _do_ mean it to answer the question, then explain why